# Drawing a rectangle over an image

Tags: android

In my application, there's an activity which gets image from the resource, i have incorporated panning and zooming functionality in the same.

What i want now is to draw a rectangle over it in such a way that the rectangle too shall zoom and pan with the image. I tried extending view and overriding the draw. Only the rectangle comes and not the image. Would be very helpful if someone could assist me.

```
public class XYZ extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Touch" ;
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
     ImageView mapView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.jubileemap);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inDither= false;       
         options.inInputShareable=true;
         options.inTempStorage=new byte[8*1024];

        mapView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.abc);        

        mBitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(XYZ.this.getResources(),R.drawable.pqr, options);
        mapView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

        mapView.setOnTouchListener(JubileeMaps.this);

    }
     @Override
        public void onLowMemory(){
        Log.e("low memory", "low");  
         System.gc();
       }
     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mapView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            // Dump touch event to log
            dumpEvent(event);
            // Handle touch events here...
            /*spacing(event);
                midPoint(point,event);*/
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                            event.getY() - start.y);
                }  else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                }
                break;

            }

            // Perform the transformation
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }
        private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,
                    "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int action = event.getAction();
            int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);
            if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                    || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                sb.append("(pid " ).append(
                        action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                sb.append(")" );
            }
            sb.append("[" );
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                sb.append("#" ).append(i);
                sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));
                sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));
                sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));
                if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                    sb.append(";" );
            }
            sb.append("]" );
            Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
        }
        @Override
          public void onPause()
          {
            super.onPause();
            System.gc();
          }
        @Override
          protected void onResume()
          {
            super.onResume();
            System.gc();            
          }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.gc();

         mapView.setImageBitmap(null); 
         mBitmap.recycle();
        }


}
```

And the xml i'm using is:

```
<ImageZoomView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/zoomview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
```

This is the code i'm using..now on top of the image i wanna draw a recagle to mark an area which will zoom in and out as my image does.But have been unable to implements this.

Comment: can you post the code of the overloaded draw method?

Comment: i'm just using the Canvas for drawing the rectangle over it..that's one way, and the other thing i tried on was to create a private class, and extend the view and override onDraw method, both ways i'm not getting what i desire, either i get the map or the rectangle.Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You should override the onDraw method.

Be sure to leave the call to super.onDraw() and do your custom drawing below that line.

See this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html

Comment: I have tried that, but what happens is when i use only canvas for drawing i don't get the rectangle and when i override the onDraw method only the rectangle comes. I have put my code and xml. If you could please check onto that and suggest me with something, if possible provide me link to demo. Thanks.